# Formatting large amounts of JSON

Tags: python, json, xcode, formatting

I've successfully scraped about a megabyte of data from my school's course registration system. I build an object graph then saving it as JSON.

Python gives me a giant mashed up string of JSON in a file, and I want to format it nicely with a text editor. I figured that if I open it in Xcode and replace commas with newline + comma, I'd be halfway home. Then I can hit control + i, and then Xcode would indent for me.

Search and replace, indentation, and syntax highlighting all seem to arbitrarily break somewhere in the middle. I suspect malformed JSON, but the data is large enough that I can't simply eyeball the problem and tweak something myself.

I'm writing the data using this code:

```
file_object = open(file_name,'wb')

json_data = jsonpickle.encode(data)

file_object.write(json_data)
```

Any idea how to diagnose the problem, or what the issue might be?

Comment: What is `jsonpickle`, and why don't you simply use the built-in `json`  library which has a `dumps` method that can indent for you?

Comment: `data` is a bunch of custom objects, but I'll look into `json`. What kind of object(s) do I pass to `json`?

Answer (score 1):

Note that json dumping has an indent parameter.

```
>>> print json.dumps({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
{"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2}
>>> print json.dumps({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, indent=4)
{
    "a": 1, 
    "c": 3, 
    "b": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to write a script for this, use `json.tool` module:

```
$ cat foo.json 
{ "a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2
}
$ python -mjson.tool foo.json 
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
```

It can also verify your json syntax:

```
$ cat bar.json 
{ "a": 1 @#!@ not a proper json }
$ python -mjson.tool bar.json 
Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsonlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) command line tool.

It will check your JSON for errors and output it in formatted way, if you like.

I use it from `vim` editor, sending current file as input and getting formatted output back (or error, where it fails).

You can also reformat or validate on command line and follow on with the file in your editor afterwards.

I have compared the python command line check (which is for Pythonist always at hand) with result of `jsonlint` on following file:

```
{
    "camera_matrix": [
        [
            532.80990646,
            0.0,
            342.49522219
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            532.93344713,
            233.88792491,
        ],
        [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
        ]
    ],
    "dist_coeff": [
        -0.281325798,
        0.0291150014,
        0.00121234399,
        -0.000140823665,
        0.154861424
    ]
}
```

python version:

```
$ python -m json.tool invalid.json
No JSON object could be decoded
```

`jsonlint`:

```
$ jsonlint invalid.json
[Error: Parse error on line 1:
...3.88792491,
        ],
        [

-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']']
```

To me `jsonlint` gave better answer. At the same time I have to admit, one has to come through some extra installation steps compared to having Python already installed, but on my development machine I do not mind that.

Comment: @m.wasowski I made a quick test comparing python version of command line reformatting with `jsonlint`. Valid JSON document looks nice in both cases, but if I added one extra comma into a list, python version simply complained "No JSON object could be decoded" while `jsonlint` told me exact position and expected content. I am using Python 2.7. On your example of broken JSON I get the same output as you show.

Comment: Just show me difference. Json.tool point to the first error, see my answer. I don't use your tool so i don't know difference.

Comment: @m.wasowski sample added. Anyway, thanks for showing the python only sample, it can help a lot when sawing world on remote linux server.

Comment: oh, right, trailing coma... That's thing that sucks in JSON (version control!). Thanks for showing this case. Yes, looks like jsonlint is better at it (even better than Perl's `json_xs`) but it all depends what you need. For simple things I prefer stuff that's already there on any decent OS... BTW, in case of trailing coma, you can `with open('invalid.json') as f: print ast.literal_eval(f.read())`. Comes handy :)

Comment: @m.wasowski nice. So I tried it in iPython console and found this trick: `%load invalid.json` and follow by `data = _`. It works.

Comment: if you are curious what exactly happened when you did, start a new question ;) But you can figure it out, I think. And why it is unsafe... EOT here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `json` rather than `jsonpickle`..

```
import json

with open(file_name,'rw+') as data:
    json_data = json.loads(data.read())
    data.seek(0)
    json.dump(json_data, data, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
    data.truncate()
```

That will open the file, load the json object, then overwrite the file with a formatted output.